# How to validate json request body in MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application serializes various models and sends them via HTTP requests to a third party.

I'd like to deserialize the request body to this or that model depending on the integration test and then assert on it.  It looks like some people might implement their own `RequestMatcher` or just assert against the string but both of those options seem dirty.  If I implemented my own `RequestMatcher` I would have to implement a different `RequestMatcher` for each model that the body could be (and there are many).

It would be nice if I could just deserialize the json in the request body and do what I want with it outside of the declarative matching stuff.

Something like this:

```
BodyCaptor captor = new BodyCaptor(); // I made this up

MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();

mockServer
    .expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(testBaseUri + testApiPath))
    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andCaptureBody(captor)
    .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess());

MyModel mymodel = objectMapper.deserialize(captor.getValue())

assertThat(mymodel.getWhateverProperty()).isEqualTo(5)
....
```

Is something like this possible?  What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a single `RequestMatcher` that used a Jackson `ObjectMapper` and took an `expectedObject`.  This way, I could deserialize to the `expectedObject`'s type and do a field by field comparison.

```
public class MyRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRequestMatcher.class);

    private Object expectedPayload;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MyRequestMatcher (Object expectedPayload, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.expectedPayload = expectedPayload;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void match(ClientHttpRequest clientHttpRequest) throws IOException, AssertionError {
        byte[] requestBodyBytes = ((ByteArrayOutputStream)clientHttpRequest.getBody()).toByteArray();
        String requestBody = new String(requestBodyBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Object actualPayload = objectMapper.readValue(requestBody, expectedPayload.getClass());

        // do this in a try catch so we can log the meaningful message from our assertion 
        // library before rethrowing - otherwise it gets swallowed by mockServer
        try {
            assertThat(actualPayload).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expectedPayload)
        } catch (AssertionError error) {
            LOG.error(error.getMessage());
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can just do something like the following in a test:

```
MyObject expectedPayload = new MyObject();
expectedPayload.setField1("expectedValueforField1");
expectedPayload.setField2("expectedValueforField2");

mockServer
    .expect(MockRestRequestMatchers
            .requestTo("http://myurl.com/mypath"))
    .andExpect(new MyRequestMatcher(expectedPayload, objectMapper))
    .andRespond(request -> {
        return MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess().createResponse(request);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the properties using [MockRestRequestMatchers.jsonPath](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/match/MockRestRequestMatchers.html#jsonPath-java.lang.String-org.hamcrest.Matcher-) to validate json property and it's value

```
mockServer
.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(testBaseUri + testApiPath))
.andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
.andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.jsonPath("$.property", Matchers.equalToIgnoringCase("value")))
.andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only need it once you could use a lambda

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
.andExpect(clientHttpRequest -> bos.write(((ByteArrayOutputStream) clientHttpRequest.getBody()).toByteArray()))
...
```